# Instruments, Increase in Allocations of iPhone application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am using UIPageViewController to load multiple view controllers. When I run my application in Instruments tool. I found that the allocations are moving to high margin. 
Though I am releasing and making the class object to nil. The allocations keep on increasing when I move to and fro . What am I missing ?

Please find the screenshot[image]

Comment: what is missing is your code, otherwise we can only speculate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the "Overall Allocations" figure. This number tells you how many objects have been created since the start of the process–the amount will never decrease.

If you want to know how many objects are there at a given time you have to look at the "# Living" column.

Comment: So you mean, The All allocations is for the size of the application used from the starting ? How Can I find the current size of the application ?

Comment: Because, I am having another application which streams the video online. So there the All Allocation sizes will increase and decrease rapidly

Comment: The "# Overall" column shows the number of allocations per type of object. It does not take deallocated objects into account and never decreases.

Answer (score 2):

Turn Zombies off. By default Zombies are never deleted, so in Instruments all you see is increasing memory usage. Note that the bars are all solid blue, nothing has been deleted.